# Allowing subdomains in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an app that pulls subdomains from the database table.
Let's say I have a tblSubdomain with 5 record:
site1 site2, etc.
When testing locally I'm adding these values to hosts file:
site1.mysite.com
site2.mysite.com

and then I do custom routing based on the subdomain.

When deploying to azure it doesn't work:

I now try to access: site1.mysite.azurewebsites.net and it says page doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use sub-domains with Azure Web Sites (as well as Azure Cloud Services), you have to opt-in for `your own domain`!

Check out the following articles on how to use custom (**own**) domain name with:

- [Azure Web Sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/)
- [Azure Cloud Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After doing all of that, everything works except for subdomains. I have three entries:  1. CNAME- awverify -awverify.mydomain.azurewebsites.net  2. A - * - myIP. 3. A - @ -  myIP but when I go to a subdomain I'm getting Error 404 file not found

Comment: What also interesting is that I can only access my website by using mydomain.com but not by my IP

Comment: would you update your question with the new information, and include exactly what have you configured and what didn't work. Along with portal screenshots! You have to explicitly configure every sub-domain (in the portal) you want to use with Azure WebSites. This is not the case with Cloud Services.

Comment: I would be surprised if you ever have success in accessing an Azure Website by IP Address only. This is only possible for Virtual Machines and Cloud Services. For WebSites you have to **always** use domain to access it.